# how to install whonix getway using broadband usb for network connection

Tags: whonix

hello i have  been installing  whonix getaway, but this always show error when when tor check the network . it shows bug error saying my network is not connected . 
i'm using a broadband to receive internet connection in my local area . i don't know  the procedure to follow on proxi edit for the virtual box . please help me for this [image]